# Replace Text and insert image Microsoft word VBA efficiency and reliability

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following code that:

1) Opens a dialog to select an image file

1) loops through all active/open documents

2) searches the body of each document for all occurrences of FindText string, inserts an image at the spot of the text, and deletes the text. (image is not re-sized/edited) - uses .InlineShapes.AddPicture

3) searches each documents header several pages after the beginning of the document, inserts an image if the text is found, and deletes the text. (image is re-sized, must be "in front of text", and is positioned at a specific spot in the header) - uses .Shapes.AddPicture

This code functions but is not stable. Images/text are not always inserted or found in every active document open. Also I do not believe I am using the correct method inserting an image that is re-sized, "in front of text", and positioned at a specific spot.

My two questions:

*How can I make this code stable and reliable?*

*Is the insertion of images correct? If not how do I correct the problem?*

```
Sub InsertImagesAllDocumentsV4()

Dim n, c As Integer
n = Application.Documents.Count
c = 1

Dim r As Range
Dim FindText As String
FindText = "[ImagePlaceHolder]"
Dim imageFullPath As String
'Open FileChooser
With Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen)
    If .Display Then
       imageFullPath = WordBasic.FilenameInfo$(.Name, 1)
    Else
      MsgBox "No image selected"
      Exit Sub
    End If
End With


Windows(c).Activate


Do
   'Search body of document
    With Selection
    .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = FindText
        ' Loop until Word can no longer
        ' find the search string, inserting the specified image at each location
        Do While .Execute
            Selection.MoveRight
            Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=imageFullPath,        LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
        Loop
    End With
End With


   'Search header of document and move to page 4
   Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdScreen, Count:=4
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
    With Selection
            .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

            With .Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = FindText
                ' Loop until Word can no longer
                ' find the search string, inserting the specified image at each location
                Do While .Execute
                    Selection.MoveRight
                    Dim SHP 'As Shape
                    Set SHP = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=imageFullPath, _
                        LinkToFile:=False, _
                        SaveWithDocument:=True, _
                        Left:=5, _
                        Top:=-20, _
                        Anchor:=Selection.Range)
                        With SHP
                           ''in front of text already converted'
                           '.ConvertToShape
                            'keep ratio
                            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                            'adjust width to 0.5 inche
                            .Width = InchesToPoints(0.5)
                        End With
                Loop

            End With
        End With

    'Delete placholder text Main
    With Selection.Find
    .Text = FindText
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
        Windows(c).Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

' Exit header view
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument


    'Delete placholder text header
    With Selection.Find
    .Text = FindText
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
        Windows(c).Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    c = c + 1

    On Error Resume Next
    Windows(c).Activate

Loop Until c > n


End Sub
```

Comment: please describe what 'unstable' means. Your code is quite long and it would be difficult to replicate it on my computer. So, what kind of errors you have? which line?, etc.

Comment: image insertion is correct but you could try to insert `InlineShape` instead of `Shape`. Again, do you have any problem with your pictures?

Comment: at the start of the header image insertion `ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader` The image is not inserted in every document header (if I have 4 documents open with the placeholder text in each document header, then the image is not replaced in every document)

Comment: btw thanks KazJaw. you have been helpful for the past couple of days. I know this question was not asked in a good way because I'm really not sure what the problem is and I can not always replicate the problem either.

Comment: `wdScreen` is rather not the same as `Page` which your comment refers to. So, what do you want to do on page 4 and why (you move to page/screen 4)?

Comment: Yes. that looks like the problem. I need to search for the placeholder text in the header but the first page header is blank on each document ("Different First Page") So the text is not found on each document and not inserted. That is why I use Selection.MoveDown. It would be better if I could just search every header section of each document and insert image if text is found